# Why was Tom Riddle in the Slug Club?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Horace Slughorn's club, the Slugclub, was his club for "special students", but it was moreso his way of becoming chummy with kids that had high profile friends or family. So why was a muggle-raised, friend-less orphan like Tom Riddle allowed in?

Comment: Same reason Hermione and Ginny were there. Slughorn recognised their talent.

Comment: Because he was a gifted wizard and that means he's likely to attain high office or achieve in life. Note how surprised Dumbledore was when he took a crappy shop job

Comment: If I remember correctly, he also allowed Lily in his club.

Comment: Hermione's a mudblood and has very few friends too! ;)

Comment: Well, who doesn't like slugs? Oh wait, you mean another slug club, never mind...

Comment: Slughorn didn't realize that Tom Riddle was a sociopath until much later. Even his "theoretical discussion" with Tom about Horcruxes apparently didn't set off any red flags (or, at least, until he realized that it *wasn't* actually a "theoretical discussion").

Comment: Hermione and Harrys mother were the same. Talented.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Slughorn loves having connections, so sure, alot of the members of the slug club were relatives of famous witches and wizards, but what about the next generation? He also collected students who had the potential to do great things.

> ‘Horace,’ said Dumbledore, relieving Harry of the responsibility to say any of this, ‘likes his comfort. He also likes the company of the famous, the successful and the powerful. He enjoys the feeling that he influences these people. He has never wanted to occupy the throne himself; he prefers the back seat – more room to spread out, you see. **He used to handpick favourites at Hogwarts, sometimes for their ambition or their brains, sometimes for their charm or their talent, and he had an uncanny knack for choosing those who would go on to become outstanding in their various fields.** Horace formed a kind of club of his favourites with himself at the centre, making introductions, forging useful contacts between members, and always reaping some kind of benefit in return, whether a free box of his favourite crystallised pineapple or the chance to recommend the next junior member of the Goblin Liaison Office.’ -*HBP*

Tom Riddle is the most gifted student Hogwarts has had since Dumbledore, his potential was limitless. Slughorn even expected Tom to become Minister of Magic one day.

> ‘– I confidently expect you to rise to Minister for Magic within twenty years. Fifteen, if you keep sending me pineapple. I have excellent contacts at the Ministry.’-*HBP*

Lily Potter and Hermione are two other examples, exceptional witches in their own right.

> Yes, well. You shouldn’t have favourites as a teacher, of course, but she was one of mine. Your mother,’ Slughorn added, in answer to Harry’s questioning look. ‘Lily Evans. One of the brightest I ever taught. -*HBP*

Another muggle born with potential Dirk Cresswell was also collected.

> And there was Dirk Cresswell in the year after her, too – now Head of
>   the Goblin Liaison Office, of course – another Muggle-born, a very
>   gifted student, and still gives me excellent inside information on the
>   goings-on at Gringotts!’ -*HBP*

Many of his connections include famous Quidditch players, which means he just snagged the hottest players on the house teams into his club for the potential pay off if they go pro.

He also helped set bright students up for success

> And Ambrosius Flume, of Honeydukes – a hamper every birthday, and all because I was able to give him an introduction to Ciceron Harkiss, who gave him his first job! -*HBP*

Comment: And don't forget that by that point, he also had all the secrets of the Slytherin monster. That might have been quite a bit to push him well beyond "good student".

Comment: @Luaan I'm confused about what point you're trying to make. Slytherin's monster was a basilisk - are you implying that the basilisk taught Tom Riddle things that helped him excel as a student at Hogwarts?

Comment: Is it Minister "of" Magic or "for" Magic?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think HPMOR is leaking.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai It's possible usage within the books isn't totally consistent, but I'm pretty sure it's Ministry **of** Magic, but then Minister **for** Magic.

Comment: It's worth recognising that Slughorn was bang-on-the-money too. Tom Riddle did indeed become one of the most powerful and influential Wizards of all-time.

Answer (score 19):

Because Tom Riddle *was* a "special student" in terms of academic excellence.

> 'He reached the seventh year of his schooling with, as you might have expected. **top grades in every examination he had taken**. All around him, his classmates were deciding which job they were to pursue once they had left Hogwarts. Nearly everybody expected spectacular things from Tom Riddle, **prefect, Head Boy, winner of the Special Award for Services to the School**.
>
> I know that several teachers, Professor Slughorn amongst them, suggested that he join the Ministry of Magic, offered to set up appointments, put him in touch with useful contacts. He refused all offers. The next thing the staff knew, Voldemort was working at Borgin and Burkes.'

I'd expect Tom, just like Hermione, did excellently in the Potions subject, and this definitely would have sparked Slughorn's interest.